# how can i retrieve JSON object in servlet upon success

Tags: java, jquery

I am using jQuery/AJAX call to pass control to servlet and upon success sending control to another servlet. Not sure how can I retrieve JSON object set by first sevlet to second. Here is my pseudo code.

```
orders.jsp
---------------
// display orders
// on click calls following ajax 

$.ajax({
    url : "processorder",
    type : "POST",
    dataType : "text",
    data : formData,                    
    success : function(data, textStatus, jqXHR) {

        var successUrl = "checkout";    //upon success pass the control to checkout.java
        window.location.href = successUrl;
        return false;
    },
    error : function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
        alert("Oops ! Error occurred !");
    }
});// End of ajax



processorder.java (servlet)
-------------------------------

Processes data 
Set some session variables

List<OrderDetails> newod = new ArrayList<OrderDetails>();
Gson gson = new Gson();
JsonObject jsonObject = new JsonObject();
JsonElement orderDetailElement = null; 

//update orderDetailElement


orderDetailElement = gson.toJsonTree(newod);
jsonObject.add("OrderDetails", orderDetailElement);

request.setAttribute("OrderDetails", newod);    //set the session with orderdetails

out.print(jsonObject.toString());   // write object to json



checkout.java (servlet)
----------------------------
**How can I access JSON object which I am sending from processorder?**
```

any idea?

Answer (score 1):

You need to make an ajax call inside success function of your first ajax call.

Something like

```
$.ajax({
  url : "processorder",
  type : "POST",
  dataType : "text",
  data : formData,                    
  success : function(response) {

    $.ajax({
              url : "checkout",
              type : "POST",
              dataType : "text",
              data : response,                    
              success : function(response) {
              },
              error : function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
                alert("Error ");
              }
    });
 },
 error : function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
   alert("Oops ! Error occurred !");
 }
});
```

Comment: thank you for your response. So I tried nested .ajax solution you suggested. However, I am getting alert "Error"   So inside checkout servlet, i tried to do request.getParamater("response"); which is coming null, as well as at the end i am redirecting request to .JSP page which also did not happen. Any idea, what am i missing

Comment: Inside the success function of first ajax call, see whether you are getting response properly. Also, set data type of second ajax call properly

Comment: Yes, I am getting response properly. It even calls 'checkout' servlet but final redirect is not happening to JSP page. However, somehow control comes back to .ajax error function. Trying to debug using firebug, but no luck yet.

Comment: So using firebug, what i see is that POST to checkout is called & response is the JSP page which i really want to see but it is not getting redirected - any idea? not sure what am i missing